# What is the best approach to deploy N number of ML models as a scalable service in the Cloud?

Tags: nlp, transformer, aws, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I've **N (~50)** number of sentiment models of different languages, which were fine tuned on HggingFace's transformer models. Each of the models as 2-3 GB in size approx. Now, how can I deploy all these sentiment models as a scalable service in a cloud platform like GCP, so that the bill is optimized and the service performance (low inference time, or latency) is maximized.

Currently we're deploying each of our models as a separate service. For each of the model we're following the below steps.

1. **Develop the service using Flask**: We write the code for our service, including routes and logic for handling requests.
2. **Create a Dockerfile**: A docker file is created to build a Docker image of our service.
3. **Build the Docker image**: We build the Docker image of our service.
4. **Push the Docker image to GCR**: We create a new repository in GCR and
   push the Docker image to it.
5. **Create a GKE Cluster**: We go to the Kubernetes Engine console and create a new cluster. Select the appropriate number of nodes and configure the desired resources.
6. **Create a GKE Deployment**: We create a new deployment and associate it
   with the image from our GCR repository and configure the desired
   number of replicas.
7. **Create a Cloud Load Balancer**: We go to the Google Cloud Console and create a new Cloud Load Balancer. Select the GKE deployment we created in step 6 as the target for the Load Balancer.
8. **Update your DNS to point to the Load Balancer**: Then we update our DNS settings to point to the IP address of the Load Balancer created in step 7.
9. **Monitor the service**: We use Stackdriver to monitor the service and ensure that it is running smoothly and that the desired number of replicas are running.
10. **Scale the service**: When necessary, we use the Auto Scaling feature of GKE to automatically scale the number of replicas running your micro-service based on incoming traffic or other metrics.

We follow the same steps for each of our models and deploy the models as a dedicated service. However, this approach costs us a lot of money at the end of the month.

So, suggest me a better way to deploy such multiple models as a service in a scalable manner so that the cloud bill is optimized, but the performance is maximized.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

- Reduce the number of models.
- Reduce the size of the models through distillation, quantization, and pruning.
- Reduce the size of the machine type within the cluster.
- Confirm the system downscales to zero when not being used.